# How do I convert this goto loop in a while loop?

Tags: c, while-loop, goto

I have a program that prompts the user to input three float numbers and if those numbers are not positive or not digits it prints out `"Invalid number"` This is the part of the program done with `goto` loops and I'd like to get rid of it.

```
float array[n][3];
int i;
for(i = 0;i<n;i++){
    one:
    printf( "Please enter first number: ");
    scanf("%f", &array[i][0]);
    while(array[i][0]<0){
        printf("Invalid number: ");
        goto one;
    }
    two:
    printf("Please enter second number: ");
    scanf("%f", &array[i][1]);
    while(array[i][1]<0){
        printf("Invalid number: ");
        goto two;
    }
    three:
    printf("Please enter third number: ");
    scanf("%f", &array[i][2]);
    while(array[i][1]<0){
        printf("Invalid number: ");
        goto three;
     }
}
```

How do I convert loops `goto one`, `goto two` and `goto three`; in a while loop, or some kind of a loop?

Comment: How did you try it?

Comment: Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: You could convert it to a `do { ... } while ();` loop and put the printf/scanf inside that for example.

Comment: Check return value of `scanf`.

Comment: I kinda went arround it and wrote a whole nother programme for it, with an outside function  and a for function in the main function because i didn't know how to convert it directly. It works but I still want to know how to convert gotos into other loops.

Comment: Try `while(scanf("%f", &array[i][0]) != 1 || array[i][0]<0){
        printf("Invalid number: ");
        while(getchar() != '\n');
    }`

Comment: As a side note, you should not iterate over the left-most dimension of a 2D array if you can avoid it. This leads to poor data cache performance.

Comment: @Lundin But it's ok to define dynamic arrays in C? Or not really?

Comment: Depends on the circumstances.

Comment: @Lundin In this case, I think it will be fine since they are actually accessing the right-most dimension sequentially within the loop, so it's almost like they've unwrapped the innerloop of a nested loop rather than acting like they're iterating through the wrong dimension as far as accesses for caching is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

See my changes. I modified not only the `goto` case:

```
double array[n][3];
int i, j;
char * fst[] = { "first", "second", "third" };

for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    for ( j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
    {
        while ( 1 )
        {
            printf( "Please enter %s number: ", fst[j] );
            scanf( "%lf", &array[i][j] );
            if ( array[i][j] < 0 )
                printf("Invalid number.\n");
            else break;
        }
    }
}
```

Similar blocks are combined with a loop and array of words. `double` is better than `float` except in cases of very low RAM (embedded systems). `goto` is transformed to `while` loop and `break`. I suppose you say "invalid number" for negative numbers, not failed `scanf`. If the check is for failed `scanf` then it can be modified to `if ( scanf( "%lf", &array[i][j] ) < 1 ) ...`.

Comment: Did you try this? Enter "bad" and see what happens.

Comment: @stark The question is for `goto` replacement. What happens with "bad" in OP's loop?

Answer (score 1):

You could convert it to `do { ... } while(...);`

Example:

```
one:
printf( "Please enter first number: ");
scanf("%f", &array[i][0]);
while(array[i][0]<0){
    printf("Invalid number: ");
    goto one;
}
```

To

```
do
{
    printf ("Please enter first number: ");
    scanf ("%f", &array[i][0]);
    if (array[i][0] < 0)
    {
        printf ("Invalid number: ");
    }
}
while (array[i][0] < 0);
```

Comment: As a nit-pick, it is usually a good idea to avoid multiple checks against the same condition. Which often makes do-while a bit problematic to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like

```
for(i = 0;i<n;i++){
    while(printf( "Please enter first number: ")>0 && scanf("%f", &array[i][0])==1 && array[i][0]<0 && printf("Invalid number: ") );
    while(printf( "Please enter second number: ")>0  && scanf("%f", &array[i][1])==1 && array[i][1]<0 && printf("Invalid number: "));
    while(printf( "Please enter third number: ")>0  && scanf("%f", &array[i][2])==1 && array[i][2]<0 && printf("Invalid number: ") );
}
```

[Short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) is taken advantage of here.

`printf()` will return the number of characters it printed which is greater than zero if it was successful.

If `printf()` was successful, `scanf()` is executed which returns the number of successful assignments. In this case, it should be `1` if it succeeded.

If both the `printf()` and `scanf()` succeeded and `array[i][j]` is less than zero, a `printf()` to display error message is done and the loop is repeated.

You could make those `while` loops like

```
while(printf( "Please enter third number: ")>0  && scanf("%f", &array[i][2])==1 && array[i][2]<0)
{
    printf("Invalid number: ")
}
```

to make it more readable.

Edit:
If the input is not a valid number, `scanf()` won't read into the variable as the format specifier is `%f`.

This may cause problem as the invalid input will remain unconsumed in the input buffer. You need to clear your input buffer.

Something like

```
int ch;
while( (ch=getch())!=EOF && ch!='\n' );
```

maybe used to consume from input buffer till a newline. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c) for more on this.

[`getchar()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgetc.html) returns `EOF` on error. Note that `getchar()` returns *an unsigned char converted to an int*.

To include this, you may modify those `while` loops to be like

```
int ch;
while(printf( "Please enter third number: ")>0  && scanf("%f", &array[i][2])==1 && array[i][2]<0)
{
    printf("Invalid number: ")
    while( (ch=getch())!=EOF && ch!='\n' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding `goto` is generally a good idea (even though some acceptable uses of it exist). Other things to avoid:

- Code repetition. (Dangerous)
- Storing a value into your final data container before the value is valid. (Dangerous)
- Iterating over the left-most dimension of a 2D array instead of the right-most one. (Inefficient)

One possible solution to fix all of the above:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float enter_float (size_t n)
{
  const char* STR_NUMBER[] = { "first", "second", "third" };
  float result;

  printf("Please enter %s number: ", STR_NUMBER[n]);
  scanf("%f", &result);

  return result;
}


int main (void)
{
  size_t n=3;
  float array[n];

  for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    float input;
    while( (input = enter_float(i)) < 0.0f)
    {
      printf("Invalid number\n");
    }
    array[i] = input;
  }
}
```

(Ideally, the code should also check the result of scanf and also make sure there's no buffer overrun by specifying how many items scanf should read.)